# Devstack Installation Error : No distributions matching the version for oslo.config>=1.4.0.0a3 (from oslo.messaging==1.4.0.dev37.g4f929c3)

Tags: python, ubuntu, devstack

While installating devstack "./stack.sh" on ubuntu 14.0 LTS with 64 bit

Getting this error:

Devstack Installation Error : No distributions matching the version for oslo.config>=1.4.0.0a3 (from oslo.messaging==1.4.0.dev37.g4f929c3)

**Error in the console:**

```
No distributions matching the version for oslo.config>=1.4.0.0a3 (from oslo.messaging==1.4.0.dev37.g4f929c3)
Storing complete log in /home/stacker/.pip/pip.log
+ exit_trap
+ local r=1
++ jobs -p
+ jobs=
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ kill_spinner
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+ echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ ./tools/worlddump.py
World dumping... see ./worlddump-2014-09-03-120633.txt for details
+ exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That could be because of older version of pip, get latest pip and setuptools from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html or upgrade them and then again try to install DevStack.

Reference: http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack-dev/2014-August/042679.html